# NServiceBus: How to archive completed or terminated sagas

Tags: nservicebus, saga

NServiceBus removes Saga data at least in the RavenDB persistens store when `this.MarkAsComplete();` is called from the Saga itself.

Is there a built-in way to archive the Saga data when the Saga becomes completed or terminated? We need such a feature for traceability reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an internal flag in you saga data, set it to complete instead of calling MarkAsComplete and check it in your (saga) handlers.

(this way you can restart a saga if you want and you sagas will live forever)

Dose that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

When using the rest of the Particular Service Platform, all actions on a saga get audited automatically, including the state that the saga was in when it completed.

[ServiceInsight](http://particular.net/ServiceInsight) provides visualization of all of these state changes.